# How to initialize weights for simple deep Neural Network in tensorflow using for loop and xavier?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, initialization, deep-learning

I am trying to initialize weights of multi-layer Neural Network using the following code in tensorflow.

```py
def initialize_parameters(layers_dims):
    parameters = {}
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                  

    L = len(layers_dims)

    for l in range(1, L):
        parameters['W' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable("parameters['W' + str(l)]", [layers_dims[l],layers_dims[l-1]], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
        parameters['b' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable("parameters['b' + str(l)]", [layers_dims[l],1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    return parameters
```

and the way I am calling this function is

```py
layers_dims = [100,1]
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  parameters = initialize_parameters(layers_dims)
```

I am getting an error which says that `tf.get.variable` is not able to take the name of of the variable as `parameters['W' + str(l)]`. Instead when I use the name like `W1` or `b1`, it works fine.

My aim is to initialize my "L" layer neural network and store the parameters in a dictionary named parameters.

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You placed code that python needs to execute into a string. Just fix this problem and you'll be fine.

```
parameters['W' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable("parameters['W' + str(l)]", [layers_dims[l],layers_dims[l-1]], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
parameters['b' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable("parameters['b' + str(l)]", [layers_dims[l],1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
```

Here, you're assigning at the python variable `parameters['W' + str(l)]` (that python correctly evaluates to `parameters["W1"], parameters["W2"]` and so on) the tensorflow variable with name `"parameters['b' + str(l)]"`.
As you can see, the name is a constant string.

Instead, you have to make python evaluate the `parameters['b' + str(l)]` statement.

Therefore, just remove the double quotes making the string `"parameters['b' + str(l)]"` a concatenation operation that the python interpreter will execute. You also have to remove the `parameters` dictionary lookup, because it's wrong (you are looking into a dictionary for a certain key that it's not present yet).

```
parameters['W' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('W' + str(l), [layers_dims[l],layers_dims[l-1]], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
parameters['b' + str(l)] = tf.get_variable('b' + str(l), [layers_dims[l],1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
```

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**: Your variable names are invalid because TensorFlow checks if it is a valid name.

The error that you're getting is this:

```
ValueError: 'parameters['W' + str(l)]' is not a valid scope name
```

If you trace it back again, you notice that it's throwing an error from:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3172, in name_scope
    raise ValueError("'%s' is not a valid scope name" % name)
```

You can then check the master TensorFlow code base [on line 3603 here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3603). If you read this function and scroll further down to [line 3671](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L3671), you see the regex that causes this error:

```
NOTE: This constructor validates the given `name`. Valid scope
names match one of the following regular expressions:
    [A-Za-z0-9.][A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]* (for scopes at the root)
    [A-Za-z0-9_.\\-/]* (for other scopes)
```

This is why 'W1' or 'b1' works.